# cross requests from client web page

Tags: javascript, flash, web, client

Is it possible to make cross request from client web page to **any other host**? using flash, javascript or mb some other client side technology, how can this cross requests ipmlemented?

Answer (score 1):

as far as i know, you cannot, without some form of control on the other host (which implies that the other host is yours) or if the host allows it (like Google, Flicker etc.).

one way to do this is to fetch remote data using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). To do JSONP, all your script does is to create a script tag and give it the url of the remote source (hence no ajax).

you must be sure that the remote site encapsulates the response in a "callback function" call for it to execute on arrival. this "encapsulation" is key to JSONP. without it, the remote code does not execute at all. this callback function should exist in the page, because when the remote JSON arrives, it calls the callback function, sending over the return data as a parameter.